# How to nest components in cdn setup vue.js project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I have created a vue.js project by adding cdn links. I have created two components with name A and B. But I am unable to nest these two. Is there any way I can nest these two just like we do it in a cli-setup project.

```
Vue.component('A',{template: '<p>Hello I am A</p>'})
Vue.component('B',{template: '<p>Hello I am B</p>'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not call your components `A` or `B`. Your components should be composed : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Then just reuse a component inside the template of the other :

```
Vue.component('component-a',{template: '<p>Hello I am A</p>'})
Vue.component('component-b',{template: '<div><p>Hello I am B</p><component-a></component-a></div>'})
```

Then display your components :

```
<div id="app">
    <component-a></component-a>
    <component-b></component-b>
</div>
```

and

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```